# MYSQL Fuzzy Match Columns

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, fuzzy

I'm trying to match approximately similar company names between columns. I've used

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.company_name 
    LIKE CONCAT('%', table1.company_name, '%')
    OR table1.company_name 
    LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.company_name, '%')
```

As well as other methods such as REGEXP and even the Levenshtein algorithm for MYSQL with no luck. The method above seems to match ~60% of the rows but not the rest. I couldn't find a pattern with the ones that wouldn't match, since many of the ones that wouldn't match look much like the ones that do. Is there another way to match even more names on top of this method? Such as a way to use LIKE CONCAT for the first few characters of each row in the columns?

**EDIT:** In response to some comments, I've also augmented the above with

```
     OR (table1.company_name != table2.company_name) AND (SOUNDEX(table1.company_name) = SOUNDEX(table2.company_name))
```

Which gives me the exact same result as the above code, so it seems that SOUNDEX doesn't help either. Additionally, I thought FULLTEXT was inapplicable when trying to find partial matches between columns. If not, could someone illustrate to me how to do this?

Comment: soundex() and the like, but be prepared for a LOT of false positives.

Comment: You could use full-text search.